Yolov4 and Darknet Training with Google Colab Error
I'm trying to train a model using YOLOv4 and Darknet. I'm using Google Colab for training during this process. However, everything was going smoothly until I encountered an error somewhere, and I can't figure it out.
.
There is no issue with my file path commands; I've checked them multiple times.
.
!./darknet detector train YOLO/objects.data custom_yolov4.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show
.
I'm running this command.
.
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
.
I'm getting this error.
enter image description here
.
I'm expecting my issue to be resolved as soon as possible and for assistance to be provided to me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Note you are using an abandoned repo.  That fork of Darknet/YOLO hasn't been updated for several years now.  (See here:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#which_repos_to_use_and_avoid)
Instead, you should use the modern Hank.ai fork, and you should also update your training command.  See the instructions in this repo:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet
The Darknet/YOLO discord server has a channel called #darknet-and-google-colab which has several notebooks with example code to build and use the new version of Darknet/YOLO on colab.  You can use those as templates to get started and train your network.
